# Python - file.write() Throws Error With Variables

Tags: python

In my game there are Rounds (Round 1, 2 etc...). I want to store them inside of a text file to be saved.

To do this I use the following code:

```
global roundNumber
roundNumber += 1

file = open('file/roundNumber.txt', 'w')
file.write(roundNumber)
```

However, I get an error for `file.write(roundNumber)`:

```
    file.write(roundNumber)
TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not int
```

I'm not sure what to do - I **need** to store the variable as a number in the text file, but it throws an error. Help Please - Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway it will be stored as text - use

```
    file.write(str(roundNumber))
```

and when reading parse to the int

```
    newNumber = int(readNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store a str(roundNumber) and then after reading it convert back to int(). Text files are for holding text - strings.

Comment: Thank you, but the above answer gives me an **explanation** of how to do it. Hopefully that could help you write better answers for others :D!